# putting a vector from one class to another using the "has a" relationship or composition

Tags: c++, class, composition

I created a class called Read to store sentences into a vector. This class works fine. However when I want to use this vector in my new Class called Sentence by using composition, I get an errors. I also made sure to include my Read.h in my Sentence.h

```
class Sentence
{
public:
    Sentence(const string&, const Read vector <string>&);

private:
    string mString;
    const Read <string> sentenceVector;  //here I am trying to use the vector
                                         //from the Read class
};
```

These are the errors I get

```
./sentence.h:10:37: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration
  specifier
    Sentence(const string&, const Read vector <string>&);
                                       ^
./sentence.h:17:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration
  specifiers
    const Read <string> sentenceVector;
    ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

2 errors generated.

Comment: `Read` is a type. `vector` is a type. Why are you specifying two types (`Read vector`) for the second argument to `Sentence::Sentence()`?

Comment: Ok I tried vector <string>& and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What does mean `<string>` in this definition? Is the class Read a template class?

```
const Read <string> sentenceVector;
```

I think there should be

```
const Read sentenceVector;
```

Also if this data member is const you may not change it. Maybe you meant simply

```
Read sentenceVector;
```

Also the parameter definition in the constructor

```
Sentence(const string&, const Read vector <string>&);
```

is invalid

Comment: Read is not a template class. I am using Read to store each sentence from a file into a vector. I then want to give this vector to my Sentence class using composition.

Comment: @user3239138 Then do not the template argument with Read.